# Laminas filesystem cache usage

Tags: php, caching, laminas, mezzio

I'm trying to use file cache in my app. Steps I'm doing:

- `require laminas/laminas-cache-storage-adapter-filesystem`
- adding section to my autoload/cache.global.php:

```
'filesystem' => [
            'name' => 'filesystem',
            'options' => [
                'cache_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../../data/cache',
            ],
            'plugins' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'serializer',
                    'options' => [
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

- in confg.php I’m including ConfigProvider:

```
$aggregator = new ConfigAggregator([
    ...
    \Laminas\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Filesystem\ConfigProvider::class,
    ...
```

and getting error:

```
[16-Aug-2023 09:57:49 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Laminas\ConfigAggregator\InvalidConfigProviderException: Cannot read config from Laminas\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Filesystem\ConfigProvider - class cannot be loaded. in /var/www/vendor/laminas/laminas-config-aggregator/src/InvalidConfigProviderException.php:19

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vendor/laminas/laminas-config-aggregator/src/ConfigAggregator.php(113): Laminas\ConfigAggregator\InvalidConfigProviderException::fromNamedProvider()
#1 /var/www/vendor/laminas/laminas-config-aggregator/src/ConfigAggregator.php(230): Laminas\ConfigAggregator\ConfigAggregator->resolveProvider()
#2 /var/www/vendor/laminas/laminas-config-aggregator/src/ConfigAggregator.php(82): Laminas\ConfigAggregator\ConfigAggregator->loadConfigFromProviders()
#3 /var/www/config/config.php(62): Laminas\ConfigAggregator\ConfigAggregator->__construct()
#4 /var/www/config/container.php(8): require('...')
#5 /var/www/public/index.php(18): require('...')
#6 /var/www/public/index.php(30): {closure}()
```